# Flask Wtforms validation error - why is the form being submitted when an error is detected

Tags: python, validation, flask, wtforms

I can't work out why Wtforms is not preventing submission of the form when an error is detected. Instead of displaying the error message it submits the form and then I get a "TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response" because my "routes" code only has a return statement at the end of the validate_on_submit block. This means that the form is correctly detecting the validation error - but why is the form being submitted? Shouldn't this be prevented because of the validation error?

forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField, FloatField, SelectField, HiddenField, Form, FormField, FieldList
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Optional, InputRequired, ValidationError

class Vent_form(FlaskForm):

    hidden_id = HiddenField('Vent id')
    room_height = FloatField('Room height (m)',validators=[DataRequired()])
    air_change = FloatField('Air tightness @50Pa',validators=[DataRequired()])
    vent_type = SelectField('Ventilation type', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=['Natural','Extract only','Balanced'])
    mvhr = SelectField('MVHR unit', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=['None','Default'])
    vent_rate = FloatField('Purpose vent rate',validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit data')
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/Ventilation', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def Vent_disp():
   
   if 'project_name' not in session:
      session['project_name'] = "0: No project selected"

   project_name = session['project_name'].split(':')[1]

   project_choices = [(str(c.id) + ': ' + c.project_name) for c in Peter.query.all()]  
   form2 = Which_project(project_choice = session['project_name'])
   form2.project_choice.choices = project_choices

   form_edit = Vent_form()

   if form2.submit.data:
      session['project_name'] = form2.project_choice.data
      project_name = session['project_name'].split(':')[1]

   return render_template('Ventilation.html', form_edit=form_edit, form2=form2, ventilation = Ventilation.query.filter_by(project_id=session['project_name'].split(':')[0]).all(), project_name=project_name)

@app.route('/Edit_vent', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def Edit_vent():

   form_edit = Vent_form()
   
   if form_edit.validate_on_submit():

      ventilation = Ventilation.query.get(form_edit.hidden_id.data)
      ventilation.room_height = form_edit.room_height.data
      ventilation.air_change = form_edit.air_change.data
      ventilation.vent_type = form_edit.vent_type.data
      ventilation.mvhr = form_edit.mvhr.data
      ventilation.vent_rate = form_edit.vent_rate.data

      db.session.commit()

      return redirect(url_for('Vent_disp'))
```

html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action = "{{ url_for('Edit_vent') }}" method = "post" novalidate>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        
        {{ form_edit.csrf_token }}
        {{ form_edit.hidden_id(value=row.id) }}
        <p>{{ form_edit.submit() }}</p>
        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    {{ form_edit.room_height.label }}
                    {{ form_edit.room_height(class="form-control", value=row.room_height) }}
                    {% for error in form_edit.room_height.errors %}
                    <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
                    {% endfor %}
```

```
etc
```

Comment: Is the /Ventilation route important to your question? If not, I'd recommend removing it.  Regarding your issue, 1) Are you sure you're hitting this code with a POST and not a GET? 2) not sure if this would help or not but perhaps try changing your validate_on_submit() to something like     if request.method == 'POST' followed by if not form.validate():  That's how

Comment: Thanks @Ben, the /Ventilation route is returned to once form_edit has validated. The modal is on the form_edit route and the main page is on /ventilation. I've found some other references to this problem. It seems that Bootstrap will always close a modal when a submit button is pressed, regardless of whether there are errors, so I need some JS to keep the modal open if there are errors. Tried a number of examples given online but none are working for me! Might try simply flashing the messages on the main page "/ventilation" returned to on button submit. Not ideal, but a workaround.

Comment: Thank you, Sam. If you have a few minutes, it could be useful for future users if you would 'answer' your own question with what you've found.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a number of similar questions on here with a similar issue. It seems that Boostrap automatically closes a Modal when the submit button is pressed regardless of whether there are errors reported through WTforms.
To solve this requires some JavaScript / Jquery to keep the Modal open until the form is validated - tried a number of examples given elsewhere on Stack overflow - none have worked for me but this does seem to be what's required.